# Why is Double used in Scala.js for properties which do not "require" Double?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I was looking into the `Screen` class (package `org.scalajs.dom.raw`) and noticed the following properties:

```
def width: Double = js.native

def availHeight: Double = js.native

def height: Double = js.native
```

Is there any reason for using `Double` instead of `Int`? I am not familiar with the Scala.js code but to me it would make more sense to use `Int`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `Int` doesn't scale. There I said it. Most screen graphics systems have to be able to deal with sub-pixel addressing. Normally, we don't see such things outside the application, but in order to remove aliasing effects, you need to be able to compute the anti-aliased pixel value based on the real (non-integer) coordinates.

Comment: Note that the only number type ECMAScript has is `Number`, which is a IEEE754-2008 binary64 double precision binary floating point number, which is *exactly* identical to the Scala `scala.Double` type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, things that appear to always be integers can in fact take non-integer values, as @Bob Dalgleish explained.

There are also cases where a `Double` is used because values can be larger than 2^31. Although whole values, they exceed the range of `Int` and must be typed as `Double` (`Long` being opaque and as such, not a valid representation for JS numbers).

However, there are a lot of times where Scala.js facade types (especially for the DOM) use `Double`s only simply because they were translated from TypeScript type definitions, which only has `number`s. `Double` is the conservative approximation. In those cases, after verifying the original specification (often in the Web IDLs), we can narrow it down to an `Int` (PR welcome, accompanied by a link to the Web IDL specification).

The specific case of the properties of `Screen` you mention falls in the last category. As can be seen in [the original IDL](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#the-screen-interface), those values are described as "`long`"s. In IDLs, [a `long` is an integer in the range [-2^31, 2^31-1]](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-long), which is precisely the range of an `Int` in Scala.js.